# "Юноша" и "юношеский" применительно к девушкам

Tags: выбор-слова

Юноша - это молодой человек (парень). Юношеский, однако, означает возраст и подразумевает так же и девушек, как в словосочетании "юношеский разряд". Есть ли слово с тем же смыслом что и юношеский, но пременимое исключительно к девушкам?

Comment: Мое мнение: в случае юношеского разряда, слово 'юношеский' обобщает оба пола и тем самым выражает дань патриархальным обычаям.

Answer (score 6):

Это слово "девичий". Читаем у [Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/785910):

> ДЕ́ВИЧИЙ, Девичья, девичье. прил. к девица и к девушка. Девичьи наряды. Девичья красота. Девичий стыд. «Вам, людям молодым, другого нету дела, как замечать девичьи красоты?» Грибоедов.

И хотя это слово и заметно менее употребимо по сравнению с "юношеский", да и имеет ряд устаревших и книжных значений, но вполне встречается в обиходе, например как во фразе:  "Девичья сборная Копейска по футболу едет на первенство России".

Девичьего разряда действительно нет как лингвистической данности, но "девичий возраст" или "девичьи шалости" - вполне.

Comment: Почему нет "девичьего спортивного разряда"?

Comment: @user31364 Увы нет, факт, но это уже другой вопрос и не чисто лингвистический, гендерная ассиметрия присуща большому количеству терминологии.

Comment: Традиционно девушка и девица определяются через девственность, а не через возраст.

Comment: Традиционно и мужчина отличается от юноши тем же самым, но говорить о том, что в современном русском девушка синонимична девственнице было бы всё-таки сильной натяжкой.

Comment: разумеется, если девушкой женщин при обращении называют чуть ли не до 50 лет, за неимением в русском языке нормальных слов типа мэм, миссис, "девушка" - это как-бы вежливая замена "женщине", русский очень инфантилен в лексике обращений, в Европе в язык низов это всё проникало от аристократии по мере демократизации общества, потому что там она сохранилась и существовал стандарт, к которому следовало тянуться